# Getting "PHP Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Tags: php, pdo

With a php script like the below, I expected it'd throw an exception and try/catch block will catch it.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=does-not-exist;dbname=test;port=3306', 'root', '');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

But I'm getting a warning error as well. Any workaround?

```
PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/pdo.php on line 3
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently PHP5.6 throws an exception when instantiating PDO as [the document says](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) AND gets a warning error. `setAttribute()` won't be called anyways.

PHP7.1.5 do not trigger a warning error as expected.